# Unable to set a specific country on woocommerce checkout page through hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

The following is the task assigned to me:

**Set “United Kingdom (UK)” as Base Location in Setting. Set “India” country in Billing address.  Observe country on Checkout page, Billing Address.  Set this country to “Sri Lanka”, through hook.**

as per woocommerce docs i applied to following filter to change the country set on billing section of checkout page.

```
add_filter( 'default_checkout_country', 'change_default_checkout_country' );

 function change_default_checkout_country() {
   return 'LK'; // country code
 }
```

its still Not working. I have researched every where for an alternative solutuion but couldnt find anything on internet. Please help.

> Please provide detailed explanations for your answer

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this code in my local it's working fine when user have no saved country in billing address as well as shipping address (then **"sri lanka"** is automatically selected.) but when user have already entered some other country has his billing address or shipping address this code wan't work. What ever country user already entered it's selected by default.
[image]